# File transfer over Bluetooth Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using Sample Bluetooth Chat android, its working fine for chatting. now i wanted to transfer file using that code.

This is what I'm trying to do :
First, the user sends a file name to the server. Then, the server sends back that file using that code.

```
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, "file:///sdcard/refresh.txt");
       values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, deviceAddress);
       values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
       Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
       values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
       getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

but i am getting socket errors by doing that. Can you suggest me a tutorial or a sample code for android file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

For transferring files you can make an explicit call to ACTION_SEND using intents

With the ACTION_SEND intent, that will popup a menu with the application that can handle the file type you want to send, from which the user will need to select bluetooth, and then the device.

```
File sourceFile = new File("//mnt/sdcard/TviderFB.apk"); 
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Intent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(sourceFile));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sorry. Didn't notice how old the post was